# How do you use Twix (momentjs) with Typescript

Tags: typescript, momentjs

Has anyone used twix with typescript and could share how you got it working?

I have:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as twix from 'twix';
```

Moment is working fine, intellisense and everything.
Twix module imports fine and if I type twix. I can see the interface pop up.

But I get:

> Property twix does not exist on Moment

When I try to use `moment(date).twix()`

**EDIT:**
I've also tried `let twix = require('twix');` and `import twix = require('twix');` with no success.

**EDIT 2**
I ran `npm install moment` and `npm install twix` and `npm install @types/twix`.

I know moment is installed and works correctly. 
The typings file being used for moment is the moment.d.ts file included right inside the moment npm package.

The typings file being used for twix is in @types/twix npm package.

After my imports, if I type `let t = twix.` then intellisense pops up with Twix, TwixFormatOptions, TwixIter, TwixParseAndFormatOptions, etc so I think typescript is recognizing the twix typings.

#### Final Fix

This [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11170) explains the underlying reason the types are broken for packages that extend momentjs, and references the pull request that will fix it permanently once it gets merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
import * as twix from 'twix';
```

with:

```
let twix = require('twix');
```

From my understanding, Twix is written as a CommonJS module not an ES6 module hence the different import method.

a little more info on the difference [here](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html)

**EDIT:** It appears there is something wrong with the 2.0 typing of twix.  A workaround is to take a copy of the pre-2.0 twix typing from [github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/twix) and add it to your project.

Comment: Typescript compiler doesn't accept `let twix = require('twix');` but it does accept `import twix = require('twix');` as is found on the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). But even with that, the problem still remains...twix method is still not present on moment objects.

Comment: yes, that wouldn't work `let` is a ES6 keyword that replaces `var`.  Try using `var twix = require('twix');` instead

Comment: Ok, now that is strange.  Do you have both the Twix library and Moment installed?

Comment: oh I see, looks like the 2.0 typing doesn't play nice with the moment typing packaged with moment.  I got it working by copying the twix folder and the moment folder from the DT [master branch](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) into my project

Comment: YES! I just replaced @types/twix/index.d.ts with the DT twix typings, changed the reference in that file to point to node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts, where I copied the moment typings direct from DT. And it works! Now I just need to figure out the best way to do this so it doesnt break whenever I `npm install` everything and lose the customizations. How do I mark your comment as the answer? Thank you

Comment: np.  At least when I was trying it out, I removed the `@types/twix` reference and copied the two github versions of the moment/twix into working project folders (not node_modules, ie. /scripts/typings).  The github version of moment/twix were both picked up by the IDE without need for modification.  I think there should be a checkmark you can use to mark the answer.

Comment: @j3ko is this still the working solution? as per angular 4 things are a bit different now, and the `require()` method no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

> Property twix does not exist on Moment

you would need to create type definitions for `twix` that do not exist currently.

## Hotfix

You can assert `any` and it would be like you were writing unchecked javascript:

```
(moment(date) as any).twix()
```

More on assertion : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

## Proper fix

You need to make a definition that *augments* the momentjs definition. This is a bit of work and would recommend reading up on the typescript specification.

Comment: I do have type definitions loaded from npm [@types/twix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/twix). In that definition, it does declare the "moment" module and Moment interface, and adds the twix() functions to it. From what I can understand reading [this documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) then these 2 declared modules/interfaces should merge just because they are named the same?

Answer (score 0):

With Angular4 and angular-cli this has changed.  you can now do this:

```
var moment = require('moment');
require('twix');
```

or

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
require('twix');
```

then when you write your code you write it normally, like so:

```
    public t = moment('2016-12-30T09:30').twix(moment()).count('weeks');
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is install [@types/twix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/twix) npm module.

```
npm install --save @types/twix
```

and

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
require('twix');
```